# iFrame Cross Origin Communication

Tags: html, security, iframe, same-origin-policy

I am trying to access parent object from one of the js files that was loaded by **iFrame** src. The page and **iFrame** src are in different domains. Due to web security and same origin policy, I am getting "**Uncaught SecurityError:** `Blocked a frame with origin "http://example.com:1211" from accessing a cross-origin frame"`.

Need to access a parent object and set to one of the iFrame variable. So, I lost the option of **window.postMessage()**. Is there any way to solve this issue ? Please suggest some ways.

Comment: How do you mean `I lost the option of window.postMessage()` - that should work?

Comment: I am using session.js in the parent and want to access the object in the iframe source. If i am trying to convert the object to string, so that i can send through postmessage. But getting, Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON. I am new to this field, can you suggest me anything else ? Bcz i hv to communicate with the parent in many places in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Like SilverlightFox says, postMessage() should work across different domains.

Do you have access to both the parent and iframe src?  If so, you can put something like this in your iframe src to send the message:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function post(msg) {
        var msg = "Do something"; // Can be string or numeric.
        parent.postMessage(msg, '*');
    }
    post();
</script>
```

And then in your parent, receive the message:

```
<script>    
function listener(event){ 
   if (event.origin !== 'https://myotherdomain.com' ){  //Optional check for message source
      return 
   }
   var info = event.data;
   DoSomething(info);
}

// Set up event handler when parent page loads.

if (window.addEventListener){ 
   addEventListener("message", listener, false) 
} else { 
   attachEvent("onmessage", listener) 
}
</script>
```